# Create one big web project or split some features into web services?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, architecture

At what point (if at any) does it make sense to take some of the features of a .NET web application and split them into separate web services?

For example, we have a very large web application that also calls a series of long running operations (our core business logic).  We also have a dll with client-specific custom features that is called directly from the web project.  Sometimes we need to move very quickly to change these client functions, often in hours.

However, if we make a change to the client-specific features (or an emergency change to the core features) and publish a new project, then it would kick all the users out the system as the app restarts.  It would seem like there's a better way ... but I'm not sure what it might be ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it makes sense to remove everything from the web project that is not involved with the UI. Put that in separate class libraries.

Do not create web services unless some other application will be calling them. Simply placing the code into separate projects will be enough. Web services should only be created if they are a requirement.

Comment: We have it split out into separate projects ... but at some point wouldn't an application be "too big"?  Particularly if we're constantly updating it (and kicking users out all because a single client needed a fast change to a dll)?

Comment: You might want to separate it into separate sites, but I see no need for web services unless web services are a requirement. For instance, if a third party needed to access the code, then put it into a web service.

Comment: What can we do if we need to quickly publish a single dll, but don't want the app to restart and kick out the 100 or so connected users?

Comment: @Jess: deploy the new version to a different folder on the server, then point IIS to the new folder.

Comment: Interesting ... but wouldn't that still kill everyone's sessions?  If not, I had no idea you could do that!

Comment: @Jess: this is ASP.NET, not Classic ASP. IIS has nothing to do with session state. In fact, IIS has nothing to do with most of ASP.NET, except for starting the worker process directing requests to it.

Comment: Now I'm real confused.  Why would IIS have nothing to do with session state?  Wouldn't pointing the application to a different folder cause an app pool recycle?

Comment: I just tried this out on my machine and I had to log back into the app - my session was lost.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Jess: IIS does not maintain session state, ASP.NET does. How did you do the switch?

Comment: But IIS manages the worker threads that run ASP.NET and controls thread/pool recycling, right?  I switched it via:  IIS Manager -> [My Server] -> Sites -> [My Site] -> Basic Settings -> Physical Path

Comment: @Jess: no. IIS manages the worker process only. It has no control over threads.

Comment: Worker processes manage worker threads, so by extension IIS manages the worker threads.  Worker threads are an IIS function, not an ASP.NET one.  Worker processes also manage session state, cache, etc.  All MSDN documentation, and my test, seems to indicate that invalidating the app pool causes an app pool recycle, which causes the worker processes/threads to reset a user's session state.  I am still not following what you're suggesting I do ...

Comment: @Jess: maybe a little of each. aspnet_wp.exe is located on my machine at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`, along with aspnet_isapi.dll. OTOH, IIS7 uses w3wp.exe, and has incorporated parts of ASP.NET into the pipeline,so you could say that it's part of IIS, even though it is ASP.NET. I still think it very useful to distinguish from Classic ASP. where IIS was everything.

Comment: So in other words, you didn't realize that the session state was lost when the application is pointed to a different folder?

Comment: @Jess: I didn't notice it, or else, back in 2004, it didn't happen. In fact, I don't know why it _would_ happen. did it terminate the original requests? That definitely didn't happen back then. The old aspnet_wp process finished after the new one started up. New requests went to the new process.

Comment: @Jess: which session state mode are you using?

Comment: Default mode (in-process).  We could certainly switch to using state server mode, although I've never tried doing so.

Comment: @Jess: you're using in-process, so I suppose that switching processes would lose the state...

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense to create service app (not like Web Service, but more like Windows Service). You could communicate between your webapp and service app using Message Queue.